# C++ - Get function name through macro

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

I'm trying to get the name of the function by using C++ macros. I'm using g++ 4.9.2 and with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
        Foo() { }

        T f(int i) {
                T r;
                std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
                std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
                std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;

                return r;
        }
};

int main() {
        Foo<int> f;
        f.f(1);

        return 0;
}
```

I got:

```
T Foo<T>::f(int) [with T = int]
f
f
```

I'd like to have something like `Foo<T>::f(int)` or `Foo<int>::f(int)` which I have in Windows by using `__FUNCTION__`. I tried to use `BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION`, but looking at the code I read that it should set the variable to the value of `__func__`.

Obviously, it could be very simple to create a function that performs what I want, but I'd like to have a macro already set to the proper value.

Comment: whats wrong with `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` ?

Comment: It is too verbose, and it's not what I want. Like I said by using Windows I've exactly `Foo<int>::f(int)`. So, I thought that I could have the same in g++

Comment: I'd say the gcc output is better - it tells you what `T` is. Why wouldn't you want that information?

Comment: This feels possibly like an XY problem. What, *in detail*, are you using this for, such that `Foo<int>::f(int)` is sufficient but `T Foo<T>::f(int) [with T = int]` is not?

Comment: I don't need the return value and other information before the function name. I can have what I want in Windows, so I thought to have it in Windows too.

Comment: You could always do some transformation if you don’t like what you get.

Comment: btw those arent really macros but predefined variables. [I was playing a bit around](https://godbolt.org/g/iwZbN7) and first was a bit surprised why they wont expand when running the preprocessor only.